# Eclipse CDT: Mapping console output to source file and line

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

While debugging code it helps to have source filename and line number on console output. I already use **FILE** and **LINE** macros. But it would be great if double clicking a line in the console output would take me to the exact source line which was responsible for outputting that line of log. Can eclipse parse console output and do something like this? It need not work all the time, only when the log line is in a specific format and the source filename and line number are valid.

Comment: The most common pattern, and likely to be recognized in an IDE, would be `filename:line:message` (colon-separated values), which `grep -n` provides.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a workaround if you add the pydev plugin and a few lines of python to call your main function. You can find the needed code here: https://github.com/oct15demo/python_calls_cpp

As noted there, I posted a query on the Eclipse forum to find out the status of any ongoing effort or obstacles to implement within Eclipse.
I could not find out any further information on the feature, if it's there, it's well hidden.

Update March 17, 2022, I shall be working on the feature for Eclipse, don't have an estimate of time yet.